# Cucumber rerun failed tests not working in chrome

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I am using cucumber and watir with Ruby for test automation and pretty much new to it.
I am trying to rerun failed tests for which I am using cucumber rerun formatter.

Tests are rerunning fine on Firefox, but on chrome not all failed tests are getting re-executed.

Is there any dependency of cucumber with chrome for rerun to happen?

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to re-run the failed examples?  And what happens when "not all failed tests are getting re-executed" (e.g. error is thrown or tests are silently skipped)?

Answer (score 0):

My bad , this was design issue rather than browser specific issue. :/
After redesigning the rerun feature flow , the issue is resolved.
The reason this was happening was multi-threading issue since multiple docker containers are involved.

Thank you for looking into it.